# When actually socket is connected in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm trying to understand, when socket is connected in socket.io. I'm using express and jade. To find out, I have something like this in my server.js file:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
    console.log('Socket is connected: ' + socket.id)
```

This message appears each time, when I open localhost in browser, and it's ok, as I understand - each opening localhost creates new connecting - new socket. 
But sometimes localhost is not open and when I start my server in node, I get this message what makes me confused. Why is this happening ? 
Second strange thing, I load my views via ajax :

```
socket.on('connect', function() { 
    socket.on('loadRooms', function(data) {
        var active_users = data.active_users,
        socket_id = data.socket_id;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'rooms'
        }).done(function(data_view) {
            $('body').html(data_view); 
            console.log(data.active_users);
        });
```

and I also don't understand why after this I get another message in my console with new socket, seeing that I don't refresh my browser... Anyone could explain me that ?

Comment: as i can only answer the first bit ill do it in a comment, sockets expire, and if the client is still connected, the socket will automaticly reconnect after the expire, if you only wonna see new sockets connect you should log on new connections, or count the number of connections every time you log

Comment: it happens in a moment, on page start I've got form, type username and click submit so it take 5 seconds, is it possible to make socket expired ?